# calculate $\int_{c}x^2y^2+zds$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $c$ be the curve which is the section of $x^2+y^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2+(z-2)^2=4$

calculate $\int_{c}x^2y^2+zds$

I don't really remember how to solve these integrals, i tried using spherical coordinates but i don't think it helps a lot, and then i tried to solve it like this

$x=\sqrt{4-y^2} $,  $x\in [0,2]$ ect

$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}x^2y^2+z\: dxdydz= \int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2} 8/3y^2+2z \:dydz...=200/9$

I don't think that's correct, how can I solve this?

Comment: The intersection between $x^2+y^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2+(z-2)^2=4$ is the plane $z=2$. Please clarify how the curve is defined.

Comment: that's the pronunciation of the exercise, precisely from my notes, i am not sure what it means, i am also confused

Comment: i don't think your comment is quite correct thought thats the intersection between a sphee and a Cylinder .  I don't think the entire $z=2$ plane is the intersection

Comment: the intersection should be the curve $2e^{it}$

Comment: The sphere is inside the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and the intersection curve is $x^2+y^2 = 4, z = 2$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you've already mostly figured out that the curve $c$ is described by $c(t) = (2\cos t,2\sin t,2)$ for $t \in [0,2\pi]$ (note that $2e^{it}$ is not quite correct because we are working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so we have to account for the vertical translation).

Using the definition of the line integral for scalar functions, we have
$$\int_c x^2y^2 + z ds := \int_0^{2\pi}((2\cos t)^2(2\sin t)^2+2)\|c'(t)\|dt = 2\sqrt{2}\int_0^{2\pi}((2\cos t)^2(2\sin t)^2+2)dt$$
The rest is standard integration, using your trig identities like
$\cos^2x = \frac{1}{2}(\cos 2x + 1)$. Wolfram Alpha says the result is $16\sqrt{2}\pi$.